# Find/Search performance in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have worked a lot with sql like databases but when it comes to nosql dbs my knowledge is limited. Planning the design of my application I asked myself if there are differences when you want to find an entry in the database and the parameters used for identification.

For example: To avoid duplicates I want to check the database if the entry exists before using the `insertOne` command. Are there any differences whether I use the `_id` field or an attribute I defined myself in the query when it comes to efficiency and speed? I think that the collection will not hold more than 10.000 items.

Because I’m able to set the `_id` field when inserting a dataset manually this could impact the overall performance.

Comment: Mongodb is not any different from relational databases in this regard. If a field is indexed, searches/lookups by that field will be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with SQL databases, you can add [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) on arbitrary fields in MongoDB. There should not be a noticable difference between reads based on the `_id` index or on your own.

> To avoid duplicates I want to check the database if the entry exists before using the `insertOne` command.

You should have a look at the [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#parameters) parameter which handles exactly this usecase. It either updates or inserts a document (hence the name, up-sert). Refer the [MongoDB Node.js driver documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Collection.html#updateOne) for details.

Comment: Are there any differences when I dont use another index? Therefore I may have two options:
a) Overwrite the `_id` with the value of the attribute I would use to compare otherwise or 
b) create an index on that attribute

Comment: Without an index, the DB must perform a collection scan (i.e. it looks through every single collection). So yes, there is certainly a difference.